# What does context annotation do in Spring?

Tags: spring, jersey

In Rest API design, I am wondering what the exact purpose of the context annotation is?

```
private HttpServletRequest request;

 @Context
 public void setRequest(final HttpServletRequest req) {
        request = req;
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The purpose is to indicate that the `request` property should be set from the context.

`@Context` is used to inject various HTTP-ish contextual data, from [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features):

> In general @Context can be used to obtain contextual Java types related to the request or response.

[API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) (Not horribly useful IMO. Or, perhaps more accurately, horribly-useful.)

Comment: The link seems to be outdated.

Comment: @florian Most likely, five years is a long time in this business.