# Allow one endpoint for one IP only

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security, spring-boot

I would to know, if it is possible for AWS or Spring Boot to block one endpoint (like mydomain.com/endpoint) to be allowed to access only by one IP address. In my case, this endpoint will be dedicated for payments callback. Is this possible?

I've found this solution to the [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920395/how-to-find-users-ips-in-spring-security). However, I would like to know if AWS offers anything like that as well.

Comment: In your spring boot you are using a EC2 instance correct.

Comment: @error2007s, yes, that is right

Comment: What port is that endpoint using?

Comment: I think it would be better to think about TLS client authetication