# how to IP white list /oauth/check_token endpoint in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have two applications (war), one acting as a `Resource Server` and other is my `Auth Server` running on two different servers. I am using `client_credentials` grant_type. I need to **white list** the IP of my resource server so that nobody else can access the **"/oauth/check_token"** end point directly using post-man or browser or any other user-agent. Here is the code snippet from auth server :

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

    security.checkTokenAccess("isFullyAuthenticated()")
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients().realm(REALM + "/client");
  }
 ... 
 some other configuration code related to ClientDetails and tokenStore.
 ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/oauth/check_token").access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasIpAddress('0.0.0.0/0')").accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
 }
}
```

I found a way to whitelist IP in spring :

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('0.0.0.0/0')");
}
```

But this is not helping in my situation because it is only checking for `fullyAuthenticated()`. I want all the resource server should be authenticated and authorized before accessing **"/oauth/check_token"**

**Edited**

I have referred to a similar kind of problem : [How to find users' IPs in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920395/how-to-find-users-ips-in-spring-security) but it wasn't helping me because in that question they were trying to authorize a resource server Api, but in my case i want to authorize spring-security default endpoint i.e; `/oauth/check_token`

On further debuggin I found that if I remove `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/oauth/check_token").access("hasIpAddress('0.0.0.0/0')").accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)`
 i am still able to use `/oauth/check_token` endpoint.

Then I tried to change fullyAuthenticated to permitAll() in AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.checkTokenAccess("permittAll()"); it started allowing everybody to access check_token endpoint. Which implies it isn't even reading the configuration from `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/oauth/check_token")`

Now I am confused how to configure hasIpAddress() and do we need to explicitly mention antMatcher("/oauth/check_token") or it is provided by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find users' IPs in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920395/how-to-find-users-ips-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

You can model it like this, which keeps both requirements - IP whitelisting and all requests are authenticated. You can remove the localhost access rule if not needed:

```
     http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(GET, "/oauth/check_token")
        .access("isFullyAuthenticated() and
               (hasIpAddress('IP_OR_NETWORK_OF_RESOURCE_SERVER') 
                or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32'))")
      .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated();
```

Comment: I don't have permitAll() anywhere in my answer. Have you tried the provided configuration and does it solve your initial problem?