# Store IP address in UserDetails instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my web-application I'm using Spring Security and `UserDetailsService` implementation for authentication.

Now I neet to get and store somewhere the client IP address for the current session and I'd like to store it in `UserDetails` instance to retrieve it where I need.

Which is the correct way to achieve this? Is there any facility in Spring MVC/Security to get IP address in service layer?

**NOTE** I also need to know IP address if the client is not authenticated (to log access attempt)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/559155/1700321.

Answer (score 4):

The ip-address is already present in the [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object (not the `UserDetails`).

You can call [`getDetails()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails()) on the `Authentication` object and in a web application and properly configured Spring Security environment this will give you an instance of [`WebAuthenticationDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html) which has the ip-address inside it. You can call the `getRemoteAddress` method to obtain the address. (See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html))..

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
String ipAddress = details.getRemoteAddress();
```

Something along those lines, you could put this behind a utility method or something to obtain the ip-address.

Apparently you want to log authentication attempts, this can be easily achieved by implementing an `ApplicationListener` and let that listen to `AbstractAuthenticationEvent`s. Spring Security issues those for each authentication attempt, and also includes the `Authentication` (containing the IP-address) into it.

```
public class AuthenticationAttemptLoggerListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationAttemptLoggerListener.class);

    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
        Authentication auth = event.getAuthentication();
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        String ipAddress = details.getRemoteAddress();

        if (event instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
            logger.warn("Unsuccesful authentication attemped from: {}", ipAddress);
        } else {
            logger.info("Succesful authentication attemped from: {}", ipAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this should catch and log everything. You might want to take a look at all the [available events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/package-frame.html).

Comment: I also need to know IP address if the client is not authenticated (to log access attempt)

Comment: The details should always be set, those are set before the authentication is actually happening (check the sources of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. If you want to log attempts simply create an `ApplicationListener` that listens for `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent` or if you want all events `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` and then simply retrieve it from the `Authentication` object.