# How to get IP address of incoming request SOAP

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have the following classes, how I can get the IP address of the incoming request  source? I have checked several solutions on the internet but could not find some suitable one, if you need more information about the project structure I can add, thanks

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "doSomething")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultValidateWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema validateSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ValidatePort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.org.com/validate");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(validateSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "doSecond")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultActionWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema actionSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ActionPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.org.com/action");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(actionSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema validateSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("doSomething.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema actionSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("doSecond.xsd"));
    }

}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.org.com/doSomething" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.org.com/doSomething" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getActionRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getDoSomethingResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Have you checked HTTP headers?  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559155/how-do-i-get-a-httpservletrequest-in-my-spring-beans)

Comment: thanks, let me check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As inidicated by Tibrogargan, it should be in the headers. You could get your `Request` injected like this

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

and get the IP address like this

```
protected String getIpAddress() {
    String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
    if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ipAddress;
}
```

You may have a chance to get IP address of the original sender with the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header if not obscured by a proxy. Otherwise the `getRemoteAddr()` should do it.