# Is there a way to get httprequest without sending it to the parameter?

Tags: httprequest

Need to work with without passing the parameter HttpServletRequest request as it is a method which is to be overridden.

```
  @Override
            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
            @PreValidateCheckoutStep(checkoutStep = MULTI)
            public String enterStep(final Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws CMSItemNotFoundException, // NOSONAR
                    CommerceCartModificationException
            {

                final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                final String guid = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(CustomstorefrontaddonConstants.SECURE_GUID_SESSION_KEY);
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559155/how-do-i-get-a-httpservletrequest-in-my-spring-beans

Comment: Thanks, that helps