# How to access the graphql query fired in the java program?

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I am creating a rest api using graphql. I want to log the query fired by user in the java program. I cannot access the query in the program. 
Following is the piece of code I have written:

```
package com.x.demo.GraphQL.Resolver;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLMutationResolver;
import com.x.demo.GraphQL.Model.Employee;
import com.x.demo.GraphQL.Services.EmployeeService;

@Component
public class MutationResolver implements GraphQLMutationResolver{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public Employee createEmployee(String name, String profile, String DOJ, String salary) {
        return this.employeeService.createEmployee(name, profile, DOJ, salary);
    }

}
```

here I want to log the query in function create employee.
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Little hint:** you cannot create a REST API with GraphQL because they're concurrent API patterns. But this is just a little hint (e.g. see this [resource](https://www.howtographql.com/basics/1-graphql-is-the-better-rest/) for a better understanding).

**Coming to your problem:** I don't know the GraphQL library you use. Maybe there is a better possibility but with the following solution you should be able to achieve what you want regardless the library.

You can always retrieve the request object as the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` via spring been or other injection methods (depending on your Spring version). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559155/how-do-i-get-a-httpservletrequest-in-my-spring-beans) for injection examples.

**Example:** Assuming you inject the HttpServletRequest bean in your class with the @Autowired Annotation. Spring will inject the proper object during runtime. You can then use the request to get the body of the request:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

public Employee createEmployee(String name, String profile, String DOJ, String salary) {
        String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        return this.employeeService.createEmployee(name, profile, DOJ, salary);
}
```