# How to access HttpServletRequest or HttpSession in spring boot service component

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to access `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpSession` in my service component.
The service component is where github OAuth2 login is being processed.
Below is my service code.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class GithubOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

        String userNameAttributeName = userRequest.getClientRegistration()
                .getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint()
                .getUserNameAttributeName();

        OAuthAttributes attributes = OAuthAttributes.ofGithub(userNameAttributeName, oAuth2User.getAttributes());

        User user = saveOrFindUser(attributes);
       
        request.setAttribute("token", jwtTokenUtil.generateAccessToken(user.getId(), user.getRole()));

        return new DefaultOAuth2User(
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name())),
                attributes.getAttributes(),
                attributes.getNameAttributeKey()
        );
    }


    private User saveOrFindUser(OAuthAttributes attributes) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(attributes.getEmail());
        if(optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            return optionalUser.get();
        } else {
            return userRepository.save(attributes.toEntity());
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my Spring Security configuration class.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final GithubOAuth2UserService githubOAuth2UserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/v1/health-check")
                        .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(githubOAuth2UserService);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new GithubOAuthExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new GithubOAuthOnSuccessHandler();
    }
}
```

I have tried to autowire `HttpSession` and `HttpServletRequest` using Lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, and also tried the way below.

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

And I am getting the error below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I am trying to access `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpSession` in a `@Service` component, but I cannot understand why this error is occuring.
Are there any extra configurations to access these classes in components?
I am using spring boot 2.4.3.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795931/5342600)
discussed in similar question.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned above, both answers on the similar questions didn't work for me.

Comment: If the answers didn't work for you, I wonder if the `RequestContextFilter` is in your filter chain. The filter populates the `RequestContextHolder` on each request.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by using comment's expectation.

The answer was to register `RequestContextListener` as a spring bean in spring configuration class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working for me when accessing the request attributes on the current request autowired in the filter phase.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this isn't the question that you asked, but if you are able, I'd recommend moving this work to the request layer instead.

Likely, there's value in your `User` object being in the `SecurityContextHolder` so that it can be accessed throughout your application.

So, first, if you create a class like so:

```java
static class MyOAuth2User extends User implements OAuth2User {
    public MyOAuth2User(User user, OAuthAttributes attributes) {
        super(user);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return this.attributes.getAttributes();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return getAttribute(this.attributes.getNameAttributeKey());
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(getRole().name()));
    }
}
```

Then that gives you the benefit of your `User` being a member of the security principal. Additionally, it benefits you because you can access it in your `GitHubOAuthOnSuccessHandler`, where you already have the `HttpServletRequest` object:

```java
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(...) {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateAccessToken(user.getId(), user.getRole());
    request.setAttribute("token", token);
    // ...
}
```